# For Apple push notification, can I send without device token?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just want to broadcast push notifications to all registered devices without having to keep track of all registered device token. Is this possible? I think it's not possible but I still can't find an official word on this. So I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In APNs, assurance of accurate message routing—or token trust—is made possible through the device token**

For more detail as mentioned in Apple documentation :

> Apple Push Notification service transports and routes a notification
>   from a given provider to a given device. A notification is a short
>   message consisting of two major pieces of data: the device token and
>   the payload. The device token is analogous to a phone number; it
>   contains information that enables APNs to locate the device on which
>   the client application is installed. APNs also uses it to authenticate
>   the routing of a notification. The payload is a JSON-defined property
>   list that specifies how the user of an application on a device is to
>   be alerted.
>
> To enable communication between a provider and a device, Apple Push
>   Notification Service must expose certain entry points to them. But
>   then to ensure security, it must also regulate access to these entry
>   points. For this purpose, APNs requires two different levels of trust
>   for providers, devices, and their communications. These are known as
>   connection trust and token trust.
>
> Connection trust establishes certainty that, on one side, the APNs
>   connection is with an authorized provider with whom Apple has agreed
>   to deliver notifications. At the device side of the connection, APNs
>   must validate that the connection is with a legitimate device.
>
> After APNs has established trust at the entry points, it must then
>   ensure that it conveys notifications to legitimate end points only. To
>   do this, it must validate the routing of messages traveling through
>   the transport; only the device that is the intended target of a
>   notification should receive it.
>
> In APNs, assurance of accurate message routing—or token trust—is made
>   possible through the device token. A device token is an opaque
>   identifier of a device that APNs gives to the device when it first
>   connects with it. The device shares the device token with its
>   provider. Thereafter, this token accompanies each notification from
>   the provider. It is the basis for establishing trust that the routing
>   of a particular notification is legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

You can not send PUSH notification without enabling on appId and with out device token.

please check programmer guide of apple developer

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html